# AngularJS app crashes IE dev tools

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have an angular application (works great in chrome and edge) that will crash IE 11 dev tools immediately upon opening.

I overwrote console.log to output to my window to try and get some information and bypass some older IE issues, and I'm getting a areq error on a controller. Iv'e gotten the rest of my app to work in IE11, but not in this one controller.

Are there any known issues with IE11 dev mode and angular or 3rd part extensions?

Is there any way to find out what (presumably) syntax fopaw is killing this single controller in IE without Dev Tools?

Listed are my deps:

```
'ngRoute',
'ui.bootstrap',
'ngAnimate',
'ngCookies',
'agGrid',
'checklist-model',
'nvd3',
'datatables'
```

Any and all insight into this VERY frustrating IE issue would be much appreciated.

Comment: have you tried having the dev tools detached?

Comment: did you try $log instead console.log?

Comment: yea i'm doing $log. I haven't tried detached. I will right now.

Comment: Detached doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a known issue with IE.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/932b6322-7a9c-4801-a30f-8403bafe1997/dev-tools-crashing-ie-with-angular-app?forum=iewebdevelopment#ed33def7-2769-4af7-831c-ef2822a44174

When I completed my GULP build process for dev and production the issues went away. IE team is supposed to be patching this, i haven't confirmed if the latest update fixes or not, but it should be good according to them.